# Why is std::variant required to become valueless_by_exception in move assignment?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have seen the following notes on cppreference regarding to the `valueless_by_exception` method:

> A variant may become valueless in the following situations:
>
> - (guaranteed) an exception is thrown during the move initialization of the contained value during move assignment
> - (optionally) an exception is thrown during the copy initialization of the contained value during copy assignment

So, the code like this

```
std::variant<MyClass> var = {...};
var = myClassObj;
```

is not required to make `var.valueless_by_exception()` equal to true (and, presumably, would leave `var` in its previous state), but this code

```
std::variant<MyClass> var = {...};
var = std::move(myClassObj);
```

is guaranteed to make `var.valueless_by_exception()` equal to true if an exception happens.

What is the actual reason for such a difference in specifications between copy and move assignment?

Comment: `std::variant<MyClass> var{std::move(myClassObj)};` is **not** move assignment, so your quote does not apply to it

Comment: how will you access var before it has been constructed?

Comment: Sorry, these were wrong examples, edited them to the correct ones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that Cppreference is talking about a different situation. When it says copy/move assignment, it's talking about copy/move assignment *from a variant*, not from a `T`. Assignment from `T` is dealt with in the next statement:

> (optionally) an exception is thrown when initializing the contained value during a type-changing assignment

The reason failed move assignment from a variant will always leave the target variant valueless is that there's no other option.

The issue at hand here is something specific to assignment. When you are assigning one `variant` to the other, there are two possibilities. Either the two variants hold the same `Ti` type, or they don't.

If they share the same `Ti`, then a copy/move assignment between their stored types can happen directly. When that happens, variant provides the exception guarantee of the assignment operation for the `Ti` being used. At no point does the variant itself become valueless; it always holds a live `Ti` which is in whatever state the failed copy/move assignment operator left it in.

However, if the two variants differ on `Ti`, then the destination variant must destroy its current object and create a new object of the source type `Ti` via copy/move *construction* (not assignment).

If variant were to provide a strong exception guarantee, that would mean that if this copy/move construction fails, then the variant should still hold the object type and value it had before the assignment operator. But you'll notice that this object was destroyed *before* the creation of the new object. This is because `variant` stores a union of all of its `Ts`, and thus they all share memory. You can't attempt to create a `Ti` in the variant without first destroying whatever was there.

And once its destroyed, it's gone and cannot be recovered.

So now we have a variant that doesn't hold the original type, and we failed to *create* a `Ti` within it. So... what does it hold?

Nothing.

The reason why going valueless from a copy is optional is that, if a type throws on copy construction but not on move construction (as many throwing-copy types provide), it is possible to implement the copy operation with a two object solution. You do the copy-initialization to a stack temporary *before* destroying the internal variant object. If that succeeds, you can destroy the internal object and move-construct from your stack object.

The committee didn't want to *require* this implementation, but it didn't want to forbid it either.